# Cannot convert from FragmentActivity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have used fragments in app. When i pass constructor of FragmentActivity class to the fragment it gives an error i.e. "Type mismatch: cannot convert from ReadFragment to Fragment". Thanks in advance for your help

ReadFragment.java

```
public class ReadFragment extends FragmentActivity {

public ReadFragment(){

}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.read_layout);
 }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
......
    Fragment fragment = null;

    fragment = new ReadFragment();
......
}
```

Comment: FragmentActivity is a activity and doesn't extend fragment so it can't be cast to Fragment !

Answer (score 0):

[FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) is not a Fragment and thus cant be assigned to a variable of type Fragment. Your ReadFragment should extend [Fragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html) instead. I would suggest doing [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html) tutorial to learn the basics of fragments and probably search the web for Java tutorials, this is the very basics of Java.

```
public class ReadFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //For more info how to implement this i highly suggest you read the tutorial.
    }

    ...
}
```

When extending Fragment you also need to override OnCreateView.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is either:

```
public class ReadFragment extends Fragment {
```

or  (and this should not work because you cannot cast from one to the other):

```
fragment_activity = new ReadFragment();
fragment = (fragment) fragment_activity;
```

Now you can chose

Comment: Why would you TypeCast a object which inherits Fragment to Fragment? That makes no sense to me.

Comment: you cannot cast from FragmentActivity to Fragment!

Comment: Sorry i read wrong, though you wanted him to cast it after changing the from FragmentActivity to Fragment.

Comment: Cannot cast from FragmentActivity to Fragment